# Trying to generate a loop that organizes complications under a new dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, data-cleaning

I am relatively new to R and am trying to prepare a dataset for it to be merged into another. Each row in the original dataset filtered_datum denotes a medical complication. A value record_id determines that patient's id so that the complication is associated with them. Complications are listed from 1 to 18 under a surg_complication variable. I am trying to generate dataframe that essentially records each record_id only once as a patient identifier and generate columns that denote each type of complication. For example, value 1 under surg_complication is a Surgical Site Infection which would generate as SSI and would be marked with a 0 or 1 if the patient had the complication or not. However, I took this one step further and tried to distinguish what side the complication was on. The code below attempts to then append _right or _left depending on whether the complication_Laterality variable equals 1 or 3 for right and 2 or 3 for left (3 represents bilateral and can be included in both, 1 is right and 2 is left).

My goal is to thus have a new dataframe Comp_summary_wide which is initialized as the unique record ids that appear in filtered_datum, then to have columns generated of each complication type and what side it is on as SSI_right, SSI_left etc. However, when I run this code, even though it generates the columns I desire, I get two major issues:

1. the complications are not appropriately marked. Even though each record ID does seem to have a complication, when I verify it with the original dataset, the wrong complication is labeled. For example, a patient with surg_complication = 1 on the right side would normally fill the SSI_right column with 1, however instead the "Hematoma_right" column, which should be filled when surg_complication = 5 and (complication_laterality =1 | complication_laterality=3) (right side), will instead be marked as 1.
2. In addition, the syntax only returns one type of complication in each row when many patients have more than one type of complication

I made a dataframe that mimics the larger true filtered_datum file. It contains the used variables, as well as one other Other_surg_compl variable that represents unused variables in the dataset. It is irrelevant to the code though.

Thank you for any help! I'm sorry for my inexperience!

```
library(DT)
library(tidymodels)
library(ggpubr)
library(lubridate)  # tools for date/time work
library(pROC) # calculate log regression ROC curve
library(oddsratio)
library(lmtest)
library(broom)
library(broom.mixed)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(matrixStats)
library(arsenal)
library(glmnet)
library(knitr)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(glmmLasso)
library(rio)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(viridis)
library(plot3D)
library(ggrepel)
library(plotly)

library(plot3Drgl)
library(rgl)
library(magick)
library(fmsb)

library(tidyquant)
library(scales)
library(corrr)
library(showtext)
library(ragg)
library(dplyr)
#remotes::install_github("ngreifer/MatchIt", dependencies = TRUE, force = TRUE)
#devtools::install_github("ngreifer/MatchIt")
#devtools::install_github("lme4",user="lme4")
library(MatchIt)
library(reshape2)
library(extrafont)
library(ggforce)
library(afex)
library(performance)
library(ggpmisc)
library(lubridate)  # tools for date/time work
library(epitools)   
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(pROC) # calculate log regression ROC curve
library(oddsratio)
library(car)
library(lmtest)
library(matrixStats)
library(glmnet)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(glmmLasso)
library(tidyverse)
library(finalfit)
```

```
complications_list <- c("SSI", "DelayHeal", "Seroma", "Hematoma", "FatNecr", "FlapLoss", "HerniaBulg", "FascialDehis", "SBO", "PE", "DVT", "SkinNec", "ImplExtrInfec",
                   "ImplRupt", "Other", "InfectedMesh", "RecurrHern", "FlapLossVasc")

filtered_datum <- data.frame(
  record_id = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4"),
  surg_complication = c("SSI", "DelayHeal", "Seroma", "Seroma", "FatNec", "Hematoma", "FascialDehic", "Hematoma"),
  complication_laterality = c("1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2"),
  other_surg_compl = c("thrombosis", "vein thrombosis", "twisting of internal mammary", "Thrombosis of vein", "arterial thrombosis", "thrombosed IMA", "loss of artery", "vein thrombosis"),
  repeat_instance = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1)
)
```

```
data.table::setDT(filtered_datum)
Comp_summary_wide <- unique(filtered_datum[, c("record_id"), with = FALSE])

data.table::setDT(Comp_summary_wide)
for (complication in complications_list) {
    comp_time_var <- paste0("time_to_", complication)
    
    occurred_rows_right <- which(filtered_datum$surg_complication == complication & ((filtered_datum$complication_laterality == 1) | (filtered_datum$complication_laterality == 3)))
    occurred_rows_left <- which(filtered_datum$surg_complication == complication & ((filtered_datum$complication_laterality == 2) | (filtered_datum$complication_laterality == 3)))
    
    right_rows <- which((filtered_datum$complication_laterality == 1) | (filtered_datum$complication_laterality == 3))
    left_rows <- which((filtered_datum$complication_laterality == 2) | (filtered_datum$complication_laterality == 3))
    
    for (i in 1:nrow(Comp_summary_wide)) {
      
       matching_rows <- which(filtered_datum$record_id == Comp_summary_wide$record_id[i])

        if (complication > 0) {
            if (i %in% occurred_rows_right) {
                Comp_summary_wide[i, (paste0(complication, "_right"))] <- 1
               
            } 
        }
    
   
        if (complication > 0) {   
             if (i %in% occurred_rows_left) {
                Comp_summary_wide[i, (paste0(complication, "_left"))] <- 1
             } 
         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi FindingtheWay! Welcome to StackOverflow! You are loading a lot of packages there  do you really need that many?

Comment: a few thoughts: 1. with the first major issue you face, it's hard to diagnose (hah) in the absence of data that is similar to the actual data. For example, you're talking about surg_complication = 1, but surg_complication in your example dataframe is a character column

Comment: 2. if you are wanting to have one row per patient, and each patient can have one of 18 different complications, and those can be left or right sided, then you're potentially looking at adding 36 different columns to your data. All of me wants to say this is a bad idea - The side should be a column, not included in the column name

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I made an error in describing surg_complication, as while it was originally a numeric variable, it was then converted into a character variable as provided in the example. Also, puns are always great haha.

Comment: if you want to upload more correct data I'd be happy to take a look :-)

Comment: While I do think adding 36 columns is tough, the difficulty is that each complication can take place on a certain side. SO a patient can have two different sides that correspond with their associated complications. I have a hard time maintaining this relationship in the data without attempting to combine complication and laterality into one variable. Thank you! I will upload.

Comment: Thank you, what kind of correct data would you be looking for? I think I'm misunderstanding unfortunately. I will say that the surg_complication variable should be a character variable as in the frame, but if you need more rows, I'd be happy to do that!

Comment: I meant correct data in the sense of it reflecting what you said in the question, about the surg_complication column being numerical. But if in the actual data, surg_complication is actually characters, then it doesn't matter, disregard what I said

Comment: What do you plan to do with the sidedness info? If you want one item per patient then building this as a tibble might be better . Tibbles handle lists as items more gracefully that do the data.frame handling functions. Then you could have a single "row" with patient ID, Right-sided complications as a list, and Left-sided  complications as another list.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you want? There's a bunch of stuff in here which generates all possible columns for each complication, even if it doesn't exist in the data. If that's not necessary, then let me know, I can clean this code up substantially.

```
library(tidyverse)

# get all unique complications
complications <- unique(c(df$surg_complication, df$other_surg_compl))

# create a vector of column names for the left and right side of each complication
side_cols <- c(paste0(complications, "_left"), paste0(complications, "_right"))

# create a dataframe/tibble with the columns from side_cols
all_complication_columns <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(side_cols), nrow = 0)), side_cols)

df %>%
  # convert complication_laterality to left/right
  mutate(complication_laterality = ifelse(complication_laterality == "1", "left", "right")) %>%

  # turn the surg_complication, other_surg_compl into one complication column
  pivot_longer(cols = c(surg_complication, other_surg_compl), values_to = "complication") %>%
  select(-name, -repeat_instance) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = record_id, names_from = c(complication, complication_laterality), values_from = complication, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>%
  full_join(all_complication_columns) %>%
  
  # sort columns in alphabetical order except for record_id
  select(record_id, sort(names(.)[-1])) %>%
  # replace NAs with 0s
  mutate(across(-record_id, ~as.integer(replace_na(., 0))))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 27
  record_id `arterial thrombosis_left` arterial thrombosis_righ…¹ DelayHeal_left
  <chr>                          <int>                      <int>          <int>
1 1                                  0                          0              0
2 2                                  1                          0              0
3 3                                  0                          0              0
4 4                                  0                          0              0
# ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​`arterial thrombosis_right`
# ℹ 23 more variables: DelayHeal_right <int>, FascialDehic_left <int>,
#   FascialDehic_right <int>, FatNec_left <int>, FatNec_right <int>,
#   Hematoma_left <int>, Hematoma_right <int>, `loss of artery_left` <int>,
#   `loss of artery_right` <int>, Seroma_left <int>, Seroma_right <int>,
#   SSI_left <int>, SSI_right <int>, `thrombosed IMA_left` <int>,
#   `thrombosed IMA_right` <int>, `Thrombosis of vein_left` <int>, …
```